# How to make local hardhat network run faster

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

I have a local hardhat node spawned simply as:

`npx hardhat node`

I have a smart contract code that I want to test that mints 100 NFTs with a simple loop. The code basically adds the address to a map and calls OpenZeppelin's `_safeMint` function in a pretty standard manner.

However, in my tests it takes a few seconds to run this function, which is a bit too much for 100-iteration for loop. I've tried enabling/disabling autominting from Hardhat config but doesn't seem to change anything.

I will need to run this function for many iterations (10000) in my tests, so the duration of the call is unacceptable. I'm also on M1 Max so I doubt it's my CPU that's the bottleneck for a 100-iteration for loop which should probably take a few nanoseconds.

How can I make hardhat execute contract code faster?

(Solidity ^0.8.0, hardhat 2.8.2)

Comment: Hardhat node is built on top of the [JavaScript VM emulator](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-monorepo/tree/master/packages/vm), which I'm guessing might be the performance bottleneck since it's an interpreted language. I don't know the solution to your question but it's worth trying a compiled emulator, e.g. [Ganache](https://trufflesuite.com/ganache/).

Comment: @PetrHejda I've installed and tried Ganache. Unfortunately it's even slower than default hardhat network. All the tests take a few times more time.

Comment: paste your code, remember that in the end, your code will be compiled to bytecode that will be ran by the same hardhat local node, so it might be your code. I've been working with hardhat for the past 2 years and I didn't had any issues regarding performance.

Comment: @MrFrenzoid I can't paste the code due to privacy reasons. but I can safely say that the mint function consists of a few `require`s, mapping assignments `mapping[tokenId] = value`, and then just calling OpenZeppelin's standard ERC721 `_safeMint` internally. if I call this 100 times (which should be literally nothing computationally) it takes a few seconds to run. the length is directly proportional to how many times `_safeMint` is called.

Comment: Use foundry for tests instead of Hardhat, you will need to rewrite your test in solidity. https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry Founry will run those tests in under a second.

Answer (score 3):

The solution below is a hack, but I've used it extensively in my tests with for loops up to 5000 iterations and it can run just fine (takes only a couple minutes instead of hours when using automining). The gist of it is to disable automining and interval mining and instead manually mine the blocks on demand.

```js
// enable manual mining
await network.provider.send("evm_setAutomine", [false]);
await network.provider.send("evm_setIntervalMining", [0]);

// create the transactions, which will be pending
await Promise.all(promises); // promises consists of all the txs

// mine the needed blocks, below we mine 256 blocks at once (how many blocks to
// mine depends on how many pending transactions you have), instead of having 
// to call `evm_mine` for every single block which is time consuming
await network.provider.send("hardhat_mine", ["0x100"]);

// re-enable automining when you are done, so you dont need to manually mine future blocks
await network.provider.send("evm_setAutomine", [true]);
```

Comment: I really like this answer!! I've a question: do you think its a good idea to put a network.provider.send("hardhat_mine", ["0x100"]) every X number of transactions within a for loop?I guess that would be the best if you want to iterate many times

Comment: @Casareafer I don't think there's any problem with that, however you should consider how many blocks you need to mine at once - which depends on the block gas limit of the network as well as the average gas cost of your txns. You dont need to mine 256 blocks (0x100) every time :)

Comment: yeah I was thinking of increasing the gas limit but I choose to keep it as similar as the real network; Actually its just how i was testing, every 10~15 transactions in the loop I mine 1~2 blocks just to not get "timeouts" :3 but I wanted feedback <3 thanks you <3

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try to answer your question in a generalised manner, however listing the methods in descending order of relevance to your requirement. Here's a guide on how to speed up your Hardhat test runs:

#### 1. **Use a Faster Local Ethereum Node**

The default local node provided by Hardhat uses the ethereumjs EVM, which can be relatively slow. Consider switching to a faster local node for improved performance.

##### Anvil: A High-Performance Local Node

[Anvil](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/tree/master/crates/anvil) is a local Ethereum node designed for development. Notably, it uses the *revm*, an EVM implemented in Rust, which is known for its performance. See [ziyadedher/evm-bench](https://github.com/ziyadedher/evm-bench) for a performance comparison of different EVM implementations.

To integrate Anvil with Hardhat, there's a plugin named [hardhat-anvil](https://github.com/foundry-rs/hardhat/blob/develop/packages/hardhat-anvil/README.md). It's recommended to set `launch: false` and spawn `anvil` manually in a separate shell which you can do using the following command:

```bash
anvil --prune-history --order fifo --code-size-limit 4294967296 -m "test test test test test test test test test test test junk" --gas-limit 100000000000
```

For a complete list of all `anvil` options see: https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/anvil/#options

Additionally, you can save some time by disabling transaction signature verification using the `eth_sendUnsignedTransaction` method that accepts the same parameters as `eth_call`:

```js
await network.provider.send("eth_sendUnsignedTransaction", [{
  data,
  from,
  to,
  gas,
  gasPrice
}]);
```

#### 2. **Leverage Parallel Test Execution**

[Hardhat supports Mocha's parallel test execution](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/test-contracts#running-tests-in-parallel). Running tests in parallel can considerably reduce the overall execution time, especially if you have a multi-core CPU.

**Steps:**

- Use the `--parallel` flag:

  ```bash
  npx hardhat test --parallel
  ```
- Alternatively, set `parallel: true` in the Mocha section of your Hardhat config.

Mocha's parallel execution runs tests in separate files concurrently. Therefore, to maximize this feature, if you have multiple test cases(e.g. for a kind of property-based test) for a given test function you can distribute/partition these test cases across multiple files.

**Steps:**

- Create multiple duplicate test files, for example, named `test-foo-{i}.spec.ts` where `{i}` is the file number.
- Partition your test cases equally among these files. To automate this:

  ```js
  import { getTestCases } from './getTestCases';

  const testCases = getTestCases(); // if you have 70 test cases then these test cases will be split 10 per file
  const totalFiles = 7; // if mocha is able to process 7 files concurrently then you can create 7 duplicates of the same file

  function getFileIndex(): number {
    const fileName = __filename.split('-').pop()?.split('.')[0] ?? '1';
    return parseInt(fileName, 10);
  }

  const totalCases = testCases.length;
  const casesPerFile = Math.ceil(totalCases / totalFiles);
  const startIndex = (getFileIndex() - 1) * casesPerFile;
  const endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + casesPerFile, totalCases);
  const fileTestCases = testCases.slice(startIndex, endIndex); // the test cases for this file to process

  // Now run the tests using these cases
  ```

Ensure that your test cases are optimized:

- Avoid redundancy: Ensure there's no overlapping or duplicated test logic.
- Mock external calls where possible to reduce external dependencies and network calls. Don't use a hardhat network fork unnecessarily.

NB: If you're using a local node other than the hardhat local node(e.g. `anvil`) then when using `hardhat --parallel` you must ensure that each file is using a separate set of accounts to avoid nonce collisions. This isn't an issue when using `hardhat --parallel` with hardhat being the configured network as hardhat likely spawns multiple hardhat nodes for each test script or maybe doesn't check the transaction nonces.

#### 3. Offloading Test Logic to Solidity:

Instead of implementing complex test logic in TypeScript, consider using helper Solidity contracts to encapsulate and execute that logic.

##### Steps:

a. **Create Helper Contract**: Write Solidity test contract/s that mimics the operations you want to test. For example, if you're testing token transfers, the test contract could manage multiple transfers in one function.

b. **Interact with Helper**: In your TypeScript tests, deploy and interact with this helper contract instead of sending multiple individual transactions.

c. **Batch Operations**: Use the helper contract to batch multiple operations into single transactions.

##### Benefits:

- **Efficiency**: Solidity can often perform batch operations faster than multiple individual transactions in TypeScript.
- **Simplicity**: TypeScript tests become cleaner, focusing on high-level operations.

#### 4. Specifying `gasLimit` and `gasPrice`:

By manually specifying these values, you can avoid the overhead of `eth_estimateGas` and `eth_gasPrice` calls. To avoid transactions failing due to a too low override be careful to set these values sufficiently high.

##### Usage:

```js
await contract.functionName(args, {
  gasLimit: 10_000_000,
  gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits("1", "gwei")
});
```

You could also consider setting this globally in the [hardhat network config](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/reference#config) using the `blockGasLimit`, `gas` and `gasPrice` fields.

#### 5. Snapshotting & Restoring (and Using Fixtures):

Snapshotting and restoring allow you to capture the entire state of the blockchain at a given point and revert to that state at will.

##### Usage:

- Before a set of tests that require a certain setup (e.g., deploying specific contracts and initializing states), take a snapshot.
- After running the tests, revert to the snapshot. This avoids the need to redo the setup for each subsequent test.

##### How to Implement:

```js
const snapshotId = await ethers.provider.send("evm_snapshot", []);
// ... tests or operations ...
await ethers.provider.send("evm_revert", [snapshotId]);
```

##### Benefits:

- **Efficiency**: Avoids redundant deployments and state initializations.
- **Clean Environment**: Ensures each test starts with a consistent environment, minimizing side effects.

##### Automate Snapshots with Fixtures:

Use [loadFixture](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/testing-contracts#reusing-common-test-setups-with-fixtures) to automate the process of taking and restoring a snapshot.

#### 6. Optimize TypeScript Code:

The way your TypeScript tests are written can impact the test execution time. Here are some optimizations:

##### a. Batch Transactions:

If the order of transactions isn't critical, send them simultaneously. You can also do this for `eth_call` requests when calling `view` functions or staticcalls to stateful functions.

```js
await Promise.all([
  contractA.functionA(args),
  contractB.functionB(args),
  // ...
]);
```

##### b. Cache Results:

If you're repeatedly fetching the same data from the blockchain, consider caching it in a variable.

```js
const tokenName = await tokenContract.name();
```

##### c. Limit Chain Queries:

Reduce unnecessary queries to the chain. If possible, calculate or infer results without additional chain queries.

#### 7. **Continuous Integration (CI) Improvements**

If you use a CI/CD system like GitHub Actions, ensure:

- Your CI environment is optimized for speed.
- Use caching for dependencies to reduce installation times.
- Parallelize CI tasks where possible.